# How to call "Angular JS" service method using string variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

is there anyway to call angular service using string variable

```
$scope.serviceList=["yearDetails","monthDetails","dayDetails"];

//controller
$scope.getDetails=function(type,index){

    if(type==$scope.serviceList[index]){

    // if i will call like this yearDetails.query(function(data){}); it is working
    //here i am getting "yearDetails"
     $scope.serviceList[index].query(function(data){
            console.log(data);
     });
    }
}

//service
.factory('yearDetails', function($resource){
           return $resource('/getyearDetails', {}, {
               query: { method:'POST', params:{}, isArray:false }
   });
})
.factory('monthDetails', function($resource){
           return $resource('/getmonthDetails', {}, {
               query: { method:'POST', params:{}, isArray:false }
   });
})
.factory('dayDetails', function($resource){
           return $resource('/getdayDetails', {}, {
               query: { method:'POST', params:{}, isArray:false }
   });
})
```

Comment: Your conditional is performing an assignment as opposed to a comparison (`if(type=$scope.serviceList[index])` vs. `if(type == $scope.serviceList[index])`). Is that intentional?

Comment: Perhaps a better question is why are you trying to do this? How are you attempting to use `getDetails()`?

Comment: my type data is coming from backend its not fixed. if i will get deferment service list based on the condition i have to call the service

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be over complicating things, keep things simple.

Create a `detailsService` that contains all methods you require.

```
.factory('detailsService', function ($resource) {
        return {
            yearDetails: $resource('/getyearDetails', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {},
                    isArray: false
                }
            }),
            monthDetails: $resource('/getmonthDetails', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {},
                    isArray: false
                }
            }),
            dayDetails: $resource('/getdayDetails', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {},
                    isArray: false
                }
            })
        });
```

And in your controller you can access the method by `key`

```
$scope.getDetails=function(type,index){

    detailsService[type].query(function(data){
            console.log(data);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question directly that how to get angularJS service by its string.

```
// inject $injector to your controller
var yourService = $injector.get('YourServiceName');
```

But still, don't complicate things like @Mark has said in his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.serviceList=["yearDetails","monthDetails","dayDetails"];

//controller
$scope.getDetails=function(type,index){

    if(type==$scope.serviceList[index]){

     //now i can able to call my service through injector in angular
     var $inj = angular.element('html').injector();
     var serv = $inj.get($scope.serviceList[index]);
     serv.query(function(data){
            console.log(data);
     });
    }
}

//service
.factory('yearDetails', function($resource){
           return $resource('/getyearDetails', {}, {
               query: { method:'POST', params:{}, isArray:false }
   });
})
.factory('monthDetails', function($resource){
           return $resource('/getmonthDetails', {}, {
               query: { method:'POST', params:{}, isArray:false }
   });
})
.factory('dayDetails', function($resource){
           return $resource('/getdayDetails', {}, {
               query: { method:'POST', params:{}, isArray:false }
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [javascript eval function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp), like this:

```
var yourService = eval('YourServiceName');
```